# Symfony2 - Hide the token label in a form printed through twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

I'm new with *Symfony2* and i'm printing a form through *twig* like below:

```
{% for form_field in form %}
    {% block field_row %}
        <div class="">
            {{ form_label(form_field) }}
            <br>
            {# {{ form_errors(form_field) }} #}
            {{ form_widget(form_field) }}
            {{ form_row(form_field) }}
        </div>
    {% endblock field_row %}
{% endfor %}
```

It works right but there's the token-hidden-field which i would like to hide wholly.
In fact the input field type is "hidden" but the label is rightly shown.
How i can print that form without the token label but with the <div> (and others) tags between ?

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem then solved by this way, you can try code below :

```
{% block register_form_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% for child in form %}
        <div class="form-group {% if form_errors(child) is not empty %}has-error{% endif %} ">

            {% if 'token' not in form_label(child) %}
                {{ form_label(child) }}
            {% endif %}

            {{ form_widget(child) }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock register_form_widget %}
```

that code above will hide every label that contain 'token' string

Answer (score 1):

On your form definition:

```
->add('fieldname', 'hidden', array('label' => false))
```

Also in your twig only need to do:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

Or at least:

```
{% for form_field in form %}
    {{ form_row(form_field) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure about this solution but you can add an if statement before adding your label like that:

```
{% for form_field in form %}
{% block field_row %}
    <div class="">
         {% if form_label(form_field) != form_label(form_field._token) %}
        {{ form_label(form_field) }}
         {% endif %}
        <br>
        {# {{ form_errors(form_field) }} #}
        {{ form_widget(form_field) }}
    </div>
  {% endblock field_row %}
{% endfor %}
```